Android Scoped Permission - Write External Storage Permission Denied
I was asked by my college to find errors on why the given app is unable to request write_external_storage permission.
They provided us with a mainActivity.java code for a simple recording application, which I feel is generated by chatGPT
Being new to android development, I have no knowledge about how android's new permissions work and I'm unable to get a workaround.
if there are any other errors in this code, please point them out.
Please help
I'm attaching the entire code.
package com.example.tryrecord;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;
    private static final int WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 2;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private Button startButton;
    private Button pauseButton;
    private MediaRecorder recorder;
    private boolean isRecording = false;
    private String outputFile = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startButton = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        pauseButton = findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (checkRecordAudioPermission()) {
                if (checkWriteExternalStoragePermission()) {
                    startRecording();
                } else {
                    requestWriteExternalStoragePermission();
                }
            } else {
                requestRecordAudioPermission();
            }
        });

        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(v -> stopRecording());

        // Ensure pauseButton is initially invisible
        pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private boolean checkRecordAudioPermission() {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private boolean checkWriteExternalStoragePermission() {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void requestRecordAudioPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION_CODE
        );
    }

    private void requestWriteExternalStoragePermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            // Check if the app is running on Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Request the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE
                );
                // The result of this request will be handled in onRequestPermissionsResult method
            } else {
                // WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission already granted, proceed with the recording
                startRecording();
            }
        } else {
            // For SDK versions below Android 6.0, permissions are granted at install time
            startRecording();
        }
    }


    private void startRecording() {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        outputFile = getOutputFilePath();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();
            isRecording = true;
            startButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pauseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Recording failed: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        if (isRecording) {
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();
            isRecording = false;
            startButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Recording stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private String getOutputFilePath() {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File audioVoiceDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), "AudioVoice");
        if (!audioVoiceDir.exists()) {
            boolean mkdirsResult = audioVoiceDir.mkdirs();
            if (!mkdirsResult) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create directory: " + audioVoiceDir.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        return audioVoiceDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/Recording_" + timeStamp + ".3gp";
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (checkWriteExternalStoragePermission()) {
                    startRecording();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Write external storage permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Record audio permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startRecording();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Write external storage permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

The permissions in manifest.xml are -
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

I tried reading Android manuals, tried chatGPT, tried other websites to check but cannot find a workaround.

If you have no knowledge about how android's new permissions work, then learn, write some example code from your hand not copy whole code from other or chat gpt. Overview: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview. How to request: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting
Nothing breaking changes in android, you just need to understand how it was done in the first place.

I tried and I understood basic permission from the documentation. I'm unable to understand what's the issue with this particular code. Please help
